# need to rewrite ANY character (@#%^&*! /)

Tags: mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^[^/.]*$ new/$0
```

everytime i type `mydomain.com/somepath/to/somewhere` it throws 404

its supposed to translate to : `mydomain.com/new/somepath/to/somewhere`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Lets parse your rule really quickly:</s>

Anchor at the start, matching anything that is not / or not any character, 0 or more times, anchor at the end.

In other words, it will never match anything, because `.` matches anything (and thus [`^.`] doesn't match anything).

I think you meant:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?new/
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ new/$1 [L]
```

<s>This reads

Anchor at the start, matching 0 or 1 / , followed by 1 or more of any character (saving this match for later), anchor at the end.</s>

(The RewriteCond prevents rewriting things in the /new/ directory, as per Devin Ceartas's answer.  The [L] prevents any further redirects)

Comment: In all regex languages I've see, characters are literal inside []

Comment: Whoops, you're probably right.  In that case the RegEx is still wrong, though.

Comment: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: how can i do that ? should i put this into httpd.conf not .htaccess

Comment: I just added a RewriteCond that should help... not sure, I don't have a local Apache install here to test it.

Comment: Forgot a character in the RewriteCond.  Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you need a leading slash will depend on if you are doing this in the httpd.conf  file or in .htaccess or in a container within httpd.conf.

To avoid rewrite loops you will want to use a RewriteCond to make sure you are not matching new/

Not sure if the $0 syntax works without capturing parentheses?